# Is it possible to run findFirst() with IN clause in Phalcon?

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-orm

I would like to use an `IN` clause in `findFirst` but it doesn't seem to work?

Expected code, or something similar:

```
$item = Item::findFirst([
    'conditions' => 'categories IN :cats: AND released < :now:',
    'order'      => 'id ASC',
    'bind'       => [
        'cats'     => $this->categories,
        'released' => time()
    ],
]);
```

I tried using `bindTypes` but there's no such "list" or "array" type (also, that would get a lot more verbose than expected)...

I know I can do it through the query builder, but I was looking to keep it a bit more idiomatic:

```
$item = Item::query()
    ->inWhere('categories', $this->categories)
    ->andWhere('released < :now:', ['now' => time()])
    ->orderBy('id ASC')
    ->limit(1)
    ->execute()
    ->getFirst();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the array and IN clause like this:

```
$result = ModelName::findFirst([
    'conditions' => 'id in ({cats:array})',
    'bind' => array('cats' => [3, 5, 8])
]);
```

Note that the above example will get the first record with id 3. However if you use find() you will get the items with 3, 5 and 8.

More examples in the [docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#binding-parameters) (at the bottom of this section).

Comment: Check my link. Its in the third code block from the link i gave you above.

Comment: I bet it must be something new. I've been looking for solution like that twice in last year and have not seen that before. It looks like it works also with strings!

Comment: This PHQL placeholer is available since 2015-07 - https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases/tag/phalcon-v2.0.4